# Determining the Approximate Solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a homework question I am stuck on.  Say $\varepsilon \in (0, 1]$, and consider the IVP
$$ x'(t) = -3x(t) + \varepsilon x^2(t) \ln (x(t)), \quad x(0) = \frac{1 + \sin(\varepsilon)}{2}. $$
If we know a solution $\phi(t, \varepsilon)$ exists, we can write
$$ \phi(t, \varepsilon) = \phi(t, 0) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varepsilon}(t, 0) + o(\varepsilon) $$
on compact time intervals.  The question asks me to find the approximate solution $\phi(t, 0) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varepsilon}(t, 0)$.

---

The first thing I did was to write
$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (t, \varepsilon) = -3\phi(t, \varepsilon) + \varepsilon \phi^2(t, \varepsilon) \ln (\phi(t, \varepsilon)) $$
because $\phi$ is a solution to the IVP.  Then plugging in $\varepsilon = 0$ gives $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} (t, 0) = -3\phi(t, 0)$, which implies $\phi(t, 0) = e^{-3t}$? or should I have $\phi(t, 0) = g(\varepsilon) e^{-3t}$ for some function $g(\varepsilon)$?

This is where I am currently stuck.  If I write $\phi(t, 0) = e^{-3t}$, then $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varepsilon}(t, 0) = 0$ and I'd be done, but I don;t think this is right.  But if I write $\phi(t, 0) = g(\varepsilon) e^{-3t}$, then this is also confusing to me because shouldn't $\phi(t, 0)$ be a function of $t$ only?  I feel like I can do this problem if I had a push in the right direction.